# How can I use query of Google Spreadsheet to sum the amount in another sheet filtering by month & date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two spread sheet 1 is record for customer data and 1 is use for check the amount for particular month. I would to the calculation sum of the amount from first sheet to second sheet with filtering by **month & year**

**First sheet will look something like this**

[image]

In second sheets the only things that I would like to show is amount. Does not have to show the date anymore since filtering the amount by **month & year**

**The Formula that failed is**

```
=QUERY('CustomerData'!A:B, "select A, SUM(B) WHERE month(X)=month(date'2021-9-30')")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=QUERY(CustomerData!A:B, "select sum(B) WHERE A>=DATE'2021-09-01' and A<=DATE'2021-09-30' ")
```

Comment: Thanks bro! you help me a lot!

Comment: Can I replace the result in the exact column that apply for this formula? which mean to avoid two cell coming out. Currently, once apply the formula it will show "SUM B" and next cell coming out result. I would try to make it in the same cell, is it possible?

Comment: yes, but I have to rebuild the data, can you share yours?

Comment: may be with `=QUERY(___previous_query____, "SELECT * OFFSET 1", 0)`

Comment: or `=INDEX((_______previous_query___),2,1)`

Comment: Hmm.. it's okay thank you so much btw. it's good enough for now. Much appreciate for your help